# one to Many relationship in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I have two models with one to many relations  such as

```
class Speciality(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
code = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
def __str__(self):
    return self.name

class Product(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
code = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
reg_code = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
packe_size = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
type = models.CharField(max_length = 256)
category = models.ForeignKey(Speciality, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

its url

```
path('speciality/<int:pk>',views.SpecialityDetailView.as_view(),name = 'speciality_product'),
```

and here is CBV

```
class SpecialityProductView(generic.ListView):
    model = Product
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['product_list'] = self.object.category_id.all()
        return context
```

**I want products list based on specifinc Speciality**

Comment: Then it looks more like a `DetailView` where you pass an extra list to the context.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I also use DetalView instead of ListView but it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want products list based on specific `Speciality`.

Then this looks more like a [**`DetailView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) where you pass to your context the list of related `Product`s (or just render these in your template):

```
class SpecialityProductView(generic.detail.DetailView):
    model = Speciality
    template_name = 'app/speciality.html'
```

In the template, you can then render this as:

```
<!-- app/speciality.html -->
{{ speciality.name }}
{% for product in speciality.product_set.all %}
    {{ product.name }}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview) instead of `ListView` like this

```
    class SpecialityProductView(generic.DetailView):
        model = Speciality
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            context['product_list'] = self.object.product_set.all()
            return context
```

Comment: it returns nothing